# Zoom/scale animation with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition, css-transforms

I am trying to create a fluid and smooth zoom/scale animation with either pure CSS or JS. Basically I am trying to replicate the first example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511285.aspx ("Windows Desktop Gadgets use smooth transitions between their concise and details states.").

The tricky part is that the contents of the element that I want to scale change when being small or large (just like on the example from Windows). They should probably just fade somewhere in the middle of the animation.

Also, another thing is that I also want it to work when the larger version is placed in the middle, so it feels like it expands from the middle. Or from top-center. Or any other corner/position.

I am not sure how to do it, perhaps there is someone here who has done something similar and can help?

Comment: Have you tried anything that you could post here. It might make it a little easier so we could show you where you went wrong, needs improvement, etc. There are many ways to implement what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started:

If you transitioning between two "elements", you can first transform the first element to the size and place of the second element and then fade out the first element.

You can see how to do that in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thorbenb/Y2UER/).

Note: If the content in the first element should not adapt while resizing, you can do the same with `transform: scale` and `transform: translate`.